# ruby module as collection of methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have a rails app that loads lots of data from some java services.  I'm writing a module that will allow me to populate some select boxes with this data and I'm trying to include these properly so I can reference them in my views.  Here's my module

```
module FilterOptions
  module Select

    def some_select
     return "some information"
    end
  end
end
```

My idea was to include FilterOptions in my application_helper, and I thought I could then reference my methods using `Select::some_select` This is not the case.  I have to `include FilterOptions::Select` then I can reference the method `some_select` on its own.  I don't want that though as I think it's a bit confusing to someone that may not know that `some_select` is coming from my own module.

So, how do I write methods of a module that are like public static methods so I can include my main module, and reference my methods using the sub-module namespace like `Select::some_select`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you define module methods within the context of the module itself, they can be called without import:

```
module FilterOptions
  module Select
    def self.some_select
     return "some information"
    end
  end
end

puts FilterOptions::Select.some_select
# => "some information"
```

It is also possible to import one module, and not import the next, refer to it by name instead:

```
include FilterOptions
puts Select.some_select
# => "some information"
```

Comment: ok i feel kind of stupid, i do this in classes all the time with self, i don't know why i thought a module would be different.  BTW what's the difference between using Select::some_select and Select.some_select?

Comment: That's a good question. When it comes to constants, you need to use the :: notation since it's not a method call, but I think you can use either for methods.

Answer (score 12):

module_function causes a module function to be callable either as an instance method or as a module function:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

module Foo

  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end
  module_function :foo

end

Foo.foo        # => foo
Foo::foo       # => foo

include Foo
foo            # => foo
```

Sometimes you want every method in a module to be a "module function," but it can get tedious and repetitive to keep saying "module_function" over and over.  In that case, just have your module extend itself:

```
!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

module Foo

  extend self

  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end

end

Foo.foo        # => foo
Foo::foo       # => foo

include Foo
foo            # => foo
```

Comment: hey sorry for the late response, thanks for the details, i'm just learning metaprogramming now so I'll add this into my toolbox!

Comment: You can use `module_method` like `extend self` in that if you put it one line, everything below will be affected.  Note, though, they are not quite the same https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/8-self-improvement.html